# Проблемы с указателями и функциями

Tags: указатели, c++

Добрый день. Недавно начал изучать язык. Вот для себя писал программку на задействование пройденных тем и есть вопросы. Суть программы-это заполнения массива, по формуле, которую я сам придумал. Программа должна вывести весь массив и среднее значение. В комментариях к программе я пишу ошибки и вопросы в непонятных местах. Объясните пожалуйста. Спасибо.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#define SIZE 1000
using namespace std;

float TempMass(float temp) // передаю значение функции из мейна
{
    float temp_log[SIZE];
    float *tl=temp_log; //создаю указатель на массив
    while(true) // вечный цикл
    {
        temp=temp+((rand()%13)/20)*pow(-1,(rand()%2)); //моя формула
        *tl=temp;         
        tl++;            // нужно ли еще раз разыменовывать?
        if(tl>=(temp_log+sizeof(float)*SIZE)) 
            break; // прерывание цикла

    }

    return 0;
}
float Avg(float *tl) // хочу передать указатель на массив, который уже заполнил выше.
{
     float avg;
     float all;
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++) //цикл для вывода массива полученных чисел на экран
    {
        all+=*tl;             //сколько раз разыменовывать?
        cout<<"  "<<*tl<<endl; //здесь тоже нужно или нет?

    }
    avg=all/SIZE; //среднее значение
 return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    float temp=20.0f;
    Avg(avg); // хочу сюда передать среднее значение и вывод массива.
             //ошибка: идентификатор не определен. А как сам массив правильно передать, вообще не знаю.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Используйте ИЛИ глобальные массивы, или динамически создаваемые массивы (через `new`/`delete`)

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему я в мейне не могу вызвать ф-цию Avg(avg); Что не так, она ведь существует.

Comment: @BigBobo, а почему (для начала) не хотите сделать совсем просто (и наиболее очевидно)?

    int main () {
      float temp_log[SIZE], temp = 20.0;
      ... 
      
      TempMass(temp_log, SIZE, temp);
      float avg = Avg(temp_log, SIZE);
      printf ("avg = %f\n", avg);
    }

Просто передаете в функции массив и его размер. В TempMass() заполняете его, а Avg() считает среднюю и возвращает.

Все передается через параметры. Просто и очевидно.

Comment: Спасибо за такой вариант. Мне просто нужно научиться правильно пользоваться указателями, понять использование разыменования и передачу параметров в функции. Я понимаю, что разыменование берет нужный элемент по адресу, но когда точно нужно его использовать в конкретном коде не уверен. В общем говоря, такое усложнение простой задачи в обучающих целях. И я все время путаюсь в передаче Мейн функции данных из других функций, по этому я создаю много разных функций, чтобы понять материал.

Comment: Да, конечно, изучайте разные варианты и что непонятно - спрашивайте.

Вот еще вариант с созданием динамического массива.

    float *TempMass (int sz, float temp) {
       float *t = (float *)malloc(sz * sizeof(*t));
       for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
          t[i] = ...Ваша формула;
       }
       return t;
    }

    int main () {
       float temp = 20.0, *temp_log = TempMass(SIZE, temp);
       float avg = Avg(temp_log, SIZE);
       free(temp_log);
       printf ("avg = %f\n", (double)avg);
    }

А вообще (на практике) лучше всегда работать с **double**, а не float.

Comment: У меня вот вопрос. Предположим, что у меня есть 2 функции-пользователя и мейн. В пользовательской функции я создал массив и заполнил его. И я хочу передать этот массив в свою мейн функцию по указателю и по ссылке. Совершенно не понял как это делать и по каким правилам расставлять звездочки и амперсанды. Помогите пожалйста примером(не привязанным к коду выше, просто, чтобы я понял) если не сложно. Самый простой способ, без усложнения, чтобы понять сам алгоритм сего процесса и в дальнейшем самому делать. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробовал что-то изобразить в ответе (сюда, естественно, не влезает) прямо в виде программки с комментариями. 

Делал в Linux (g++).

Что непонятно, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 2):

[@BigBobo](/users/15759/bigbobo), вот пробуйте.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

// передаем указатель на результат (создаваемый динамический массив) по ссылке
void arr_create (int size, int *&result) {
  result = new int[size]; // заносим адрес выделенной памяти
                          // в указатель, переданный по ссылке
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    result[i] = i * i;
}

// передаем адрес указателя на результат (создаваемый динамический массив)
void arr_create2 (int size, int **result) {
  *result = new int[size]; // заносим адрес выделенной памяти
                           // в указатель, адрес которого передан сюда
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    (*result)[i] = i * i;  // а можно записать так: *(*result + i) = i * i;
}

// передаем указатель на массив (адрес его первого элемента)
void arr_print (int size, int *array) {
  cout << "print: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << array[i] << ' ';  // а обращаемся к элементам в стиле "массив"
  cout << '\n';
}

// то же самое. что и в arr_print(), просто другой синтаксис ("массив")
void arr_print2 (int size, int array[]) {
  cout << "print2: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << *(array + i) << ' '; // а тут обращаемся к элементам в стиле "указатель"
                                 // (хотя синтексически передали массив)
  cout << '\n';
}

int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  int *array, // указатель, который будет адресовать динамически созданный массив
    n = av[1] ? atoi(av[1]) : 5;
  if (n < 1)
    n = 5;

  arr_create(n, array); // передаем указатель, но компилятор "видит",
                        // что в arr_create(... int *&res) требуется ссылка
                        // и реально передаст адрес указателя
  arr_print(n, array);
  arr_print2(n, array); // здесь в обе функции передаем просто указатель
  delete [] array;

  n += 2;
  arr_create2(n, &array);// просто сами передаем адрес указателя
  arr_print(n, array);
  arr_print2(n, array);
  delete [] array;

  return 0;
}
```